# Showing function arguments in xhprof

Tags: xhprof

in xhprof I can see only function names and their execution time,...Is there a way to know which arguments are passed to them?

Answer (score 3):

No, XHProf doesn't record function arguments.

I find that I can usually get what I need by tracing the call stack up from the function I'm looking at. For example, if it's a call to MySQL, knowing the parent will usually tell you what you need to know about where the query is coming from.

If nothing else, let XHProf show you the function that you need to look at closer and add some logging of your own to figure out what the args are.